# Spring + Lombok: Can I have @Autowired @Setter

Tags: spring, lombok

```
class Foo {
  @Setter @Autowired private Bar bar;
}
```

Spring will use field injection here. Is there currently any way of telling it to use a setter injection?

Comment: Did you try this http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX.html? But it's kinda ugly...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do this in Spring, but you could try to achieve exactly the same behaviour with
http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX.html

So it will be something like

JDK8+:

```java
class Foo {
    @Setter(onMethod_={@Autowired})
    private Bar bar;
}
```

JDK7:

```java
class Foo {
    @Setter(onMethod=@__({@Autowired}))
    private Bar bar;
}
```

Unfortunately, it's quite ugly...

Also, keep in mind feature status - they said it could be removed from lombok in future releases.