# Lombok and @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, annotations, lombok

How to inject beans using `@Autowired` annotation, if I use Lombok in the project?

The answers on these links seem to be unstable (support?):

[Spring + Lombok: Can I have @Autowired @Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685182/spring-lombok-can-i-have-autowired-setter)

[Spring support in IDEA with Lombok: Is "Navigate to autowired dependencies" supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287592/spring-support-in-idea-with-lombok-is-navigate-to-autowired-dependencies-supp)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Starting with Spring version 4.3, the single bean constructor does not need to be annotated with the `@Autowired` annotation.

This makes it possible to use the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` annotations for dependency injection:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Example {

    private final ExampleDependency dependency;

    public void example() {
        dependency.call();
    }
}
```

In the above example, Lombok will create a *constructor* with a single `dependency` field, and since this is the only constructor, Spring will inject the dependencies through it.

If your version of Spring is less than 4.3, or you use multiple constructors, you can annotate the desired Lombok constructor with the `@Autowired` annotation using the `onConstructor` field:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
```

[Constructor Injection in Spring with Lombok](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injection-lombok).

Comment: fields should be final or not?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) `@RequiredArgsConstructor` generates constructor with final fields or with `@NonNull` annotated field which  is not initialized where it is declared.

Answer (score 4):

As of Spring 4.3, if a class defines only one single constructor, Spring will understand to use that constructor without needing to add `@Autowired` or any other annotations. Simply ensure that you have an appropriate constructor.

As mentioned by @vszholobov, you can use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` or `@AllArgsConstructor`; it's usually best to make your dependencies `final`, so unless you have something like a default `Clock`, they'll be basically equivalent. (This also works with other styles of creating constructors, such as `@TupleConstructor(defaults = false)` for Groovy.)

Answer (score 2):

In older versions of Spring you'll need Lombok to annotate the constructor with `@Autowired` e.g. `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))`.