# getting symbol not found for lombok annotation after upgrading java version from 8 to 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, java-17, intellij-lombok-plugin

I've been trying to upgrade the java version[from 8 -> 17] of a spring boot 2.6.4 project.
After setting the `java.version` property to 17 in pom.xml , I started getting the following issue.

```
[ERROR] Constructing Javadoc information...
[ERROR] @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
[ERROR]                                           ^
[ERROR]   symbol: class __
[ERROR] 2 errors
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: /Users/utkarsh.s/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.5/Contents/Home/bin/javadoc @options @packages
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/Users/utkarsh.s/Development/apps/sample_project/target/apidocs' dir.
[ERROR]
```

Please Note :

- I'm using IntelliJ 2022.2.3
- My lombok version is : `1.18.22` and it is working properly with java8.
- In order to upgrade the java version for my project , i have done the following :
  -

  - Installed jdk17 `Amazon Correto 17.0.5`. [I installed it with intelliJ]
  - updated maven setting to use `JDK for importer` as 17.
  - set the project SDK as 17.

Attaching few snippets of the pom file .

```
    <properties>
         <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
         <java.version>17<java.version>
    <properties>
    .
    .
    .
    <dependencies>
    .
    .
    .
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    .
    .
    .
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you please share pom.xml?

Comment: It's a huge pom.xml with custom artefacts.
But I can share a few relevant snippets .
I've updated the page with few snippets, please lemme know if u need more info.
Thanks @RohitAgarwal

Comment: Does this clarify anything? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68538851/lombok-and-autowired

Answer (score 0):

As per lombok doc https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.16.18/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor.html, the syntax has been updated to

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_={@AnnotationsGohere})
```

Comment: getting symbol not found error on `onConstructor_ `