# dependency injection in java library using spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am new to spring framework and trying to do dependency injection using spring framework in my stand alone java library which is consumed by 2 of the clients

I am declaring my bean and I want to inject `ObjectMapper`

```
    package com.my.package.search.modules

    @Component
    public class ModuleProvider {
        @Bean
        public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
           return new ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        }
    
    }
```

my class using it

```
    @Slf4j
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.my.package.search"})
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
    public class ConfigurationProcessor {
    
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
    @SneakyThrows
    public void processTheme(String name) {
    
        String json = "{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }";
        Car car = objectMapper.readValue(json, Car.class);
        System.out.println("all gg" + car);
    }
}
```

I am trying to trigger it from

```
@Slf4j
public final class SomeCaller {

  //Some caller method is triggering this
    public void callConfig() {
        new ConfigurationProcessor().processTheme(null);
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception in

```
Car car = objectMapper.readValue(json, Car.class);
```

objectMapper -  is not getting injected and it is coming as null

I am trying to follow examples which I got from internet like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-annotation

PS: I am aware this is not best practice to integrate DI in libraries. In this case both the clients-services are owned by myself.

EDIT:1

I made changes as suggested but that didnt worked

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class ModuleProvider {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
       return new ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the spring version that you are using?

Comment: spring 5.3.x; and i tried with    4.3.x; for both throwing null pointer exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68538851/lombok-and-autowired

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the configuration created for your ObjectMapper using the config.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

Then in your configuration processor class autowire your objectmapper.

```
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
public ConfigurationProcessor(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
}
```

This should inject your objectMapper object into the context.

Comment: hi thanks for suggestion  tried your proposal unfortunately same null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that you are manually creating an instance of ConfigurationProcessor using the new keyword in your TestSpring class. When you create an object this way, Spring is not aware of it, and thus, it doesn't perform dependency injection on that object.

To fix it, one of the solution is to retrieve the ConfigurationProcessor bean and let spring to handle the dependency injection. Here is an example.

```
@Slf4j
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.my.package.search"})
public final class TestSpring {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestSpring.class);
        ConfigurationProcessor configurationProcessor = context.getBean(ConfigurationProcessor.class);
        configurationProcessor.processTheme(null);
    }
}
```

There is alternative solutions. You can try and see which is the best for your situation. Here is some key word: SpringBootTest, TestConfiguration or Mockito.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion unfortunately i cant use this solution because mine is library it is very difficult to do this context from everywhere. Since library can accessed from many entry points

Comment: What do you mean it is very difficult to do this context from everywhere? The problem you mention is you are getting null pointer exception when you running the test. The reason is because if you create an instance of ConfigurationProcessor by new keyword, the di is not involved.

Comment: hi i am not running test. I am trying to see how it can be called from other caller while using the library . I modified name Test to avoid confusion

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to use the library built with spring in a non spring application? As far as I know, it can't work on your situation because the dependency injection is handle by Spring. You can handle the dependency injection manually or make the objectMapper variable as static in ConfigurationProcessor class. But It lost the meaning of using spring to build ur library. So I don't think using spring to built your library is a good choice if you expect to use it on a non spring application. Maybe there are some way to do that in spring that I don't know. Hope someone can help you.